# BSAF stalls opening a DB connection

Tags: java, database, swing, connection, saf

Running a Java application using Better Swing Application Framework (BSAF), if I ever try to open a connection with a database once the program has launched it gets stalled. If I happen to run the connection before the launch, it works properly. In my case there's no workaround possible as I require the user to actively open and close the connection.

The following code is a exmaple of what happens

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.Task;

public class BsafConnection extends SingleFrameApplication {

    private static final String DB_URL = ""; // A proper URL
    private static final String DRIVER = ""; // A proper driver
    private static Connection CONNECTION;

    public BsafConnection() {
        super();

        addExitListener(new ExitListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean canExit(EventObject event) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void willExit(EventObject event) {
                if (CONNECTION != null) {
                    try {
                        CONNECTION.close();
                        System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection was not open");
                }
            }});
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
    }

    @Override
    public void ready() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton(getContext().getActionMap().get("connect")));
        panel.add(new JButton("Press here to check that the EDT is not blocked"));
        show(panel);
    }

    @Action
    public Task<?, ?> connect() {
        return new Task<Object, Object> (this) {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                javax.swing.Action action = getContext().getActionMap().get("connect");
                action.putValue(javax.swing.Action.NAME, "Connecting...");
                openConnection(); // Placing the connection here makes the application stall

                action.putValue(javax.swing.Action.NAME, "Connected!");
                return null;
            }};
    }

    public static void openConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);

            CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL); // This instruction stalls when called after launch()
            System.out.println("Connection open");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
//        openConnection(); // Here, the connection would work but is not the desired place 
        launch(BsafConnection.class, args);
    }

}
```

I'm working on a Windows environment, if that might be some kind of issue.
I'm afraid that might be related to the way BSAF runs the application using the EDT or about the `ClassLoader`.
Just to clarify: blocking the EDT is not an issue, it's working properly, the thing is that the instruction `DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);` gets stuck and throws no exception.

**EDIT**: I just found out that if I happen to open a connection before the launch I can open them later properly.

**EDIT 2**: Added a more explanative example code.

**EDIT 3**: Clarified info about the possible reasons

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your connection is blocking the event dispatch thread. You should handle it in another thread like a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Edit: I'm not sure why `Task/SwingWorker` isn't working, but you might look in the [BASF](https://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home) [forum](https://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/forums) on the [topic](https://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/forums/search?query=swingworker&commit=Search%20Project%20Forums).

Comment: Tried already, it's not working: either using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` or using a `Task` of the framework, which is a `SwingWorker` internally. The example is simple, that's why it's blocking the EDT (in the real implementation is not getting blocked as it's handled inside a `Task`), but the real problem is not getting blocked, it's that the connection never happens.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how "the connection never happens." Do you mean `openConnection()` is never called or that it blocks the EDT?

Comment: Neither: the problem is that the instruction `DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL)` gets stalled always after the launch of the application. I'm going to rewrite the example for clarifying the problem.

Comment: I've added an example a bit more complex but that shows the problem a bit more clear. To clarify: The problem is  that you can't open a DB connection after the launch().

Comment: I've asked this in the forums as suggested, although those don't have much activity nowadays. After thinking and reading, maybe it's related to how BSAF manipulates the `ClassLoader` and how the Driver is registered, but still I'm completely lost.